# Require solution for Error: "Error on Bar 0: Objects positioned using xloc.bar_index cannot be drawn further than 500 bars into the future."

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have developed code for one indicator in Pine Script version 5, and the code is compiling successfully. But when I am applying the indicator on Tradingview chart, I am getting this Error: "Error on Bar 0: Objects positioned using xloc.bar_index cannot be drawn further than 500 bars into the future." I have used xloc.bar_time and I am fine to limit myself to 499 bars also, but adding these lines also not helping. I have tried to add the condition: if bar_index < 500, but it is not still giving error. I tried to add max_bars_back also on top while defining indicator, but I am still getting same Error on Bar 0. Please help to fix the issue.

This is the code that I have written, it is compiling successfully, but on applying on chart getting the Study Error on bar 0. I tried to even limit to 500 bars by using bar_index but that also not working nor using max_bars_back=499 is helping.I dont want to put such condition, but at least it will be useful to some extent.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Boring Candle Zone Marking", shorttitle="BC-ZM", overlay=true, max_bars_back=499)

var line1_color = color.new(color.green, 0)
var line2_color = color.new(color.green, 0)

bar_index = 0

// Find the boring candle
atr14 = ta.atr(14)[1]
Boring_tr = high[1] - low[1]
Isboring_candle = Boring_tr < atr14[1]

// Left Leg Candle
LeftLeg_tr = high[2] - low[2]
IsLeftLeg = (LeftLeg_tr > atr14 and math.abs(open[2]-close[2]) > Boring_tr and LeftLeg_tr > 2*Boring_tr)

// Right Leg Candle
RightLeg_tr = high-low
IsRightLeg = (RightLeg_tr > atr14 and math.abs(open-close) > 3* Boring_tr and RightLeg_tr > 4*Boring_tr)

// Check if the Left Leg, Boring, and Right Leg candle satisfies the conditions
is_valid_green = Isboring_candle and IsLeftLeg and low > low[1] and open > high[1] and RightLeg_tr > 1.5*LeftLeg_tr and line1_color == color.green and line2_color == color.green
is_valid_red = Isboring_candle and IsLeftLeg and high < high[1] and open < low[1] and RightLeg_tr > 1.5*LeftLeg_tr and line1_color == color.red and line2_color == color.red

// Draw the zone
if bar_index < 500
    var line1 = line.new(time[1], high[1] + 0.001 * high[1], time, high[1] + 0.001 * high[1], color=color.green, width=1, extend=extend.right, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    var line2 = line.new(time[1], low[1] - 0.001 * low[1], time, low[1] - 0.001 * low[1], color=color.green, width=1, extend=extend.right, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

    if (is_valid_green)
        line.set_xy1(line1, time[1], high[1] + 0.001 * high[1])
        line.set_xy2(line1, time, high[1] + 0.001 * high[1])
        line.set_xy1(line2, time[1], low[1] - 0.001 * low[1])
        line.set_xy2(line2, time, low[1] - 0.001 * low[1])

    // Repeat the above block for is_valid_red condition
    // Get the color of the lines
    var line1_color_val = color(line1_color)
    var line2_color_val = color(line2_color)

// Count the number of zones
zone_count = 0
for i = 0 to time
    if line.get_x2(line.new(i, 0, i, 0)) == time
        zone_count += 1

// Print the number of zones
plotchar(zone_count, "Zones", "", location.top)
```